# Как сделать, чтобы Recyclerview scroll продолжал скроллиться?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Как сделать, чтобы скролл recyclerview не упирался в конец списка, а продолжал скроллиться немного. 
То есть я могу потянуть скролл, но он сразу остановится, как только дойдет до конца. А мне нужно, чтобы он резиново продолжал тянуться дальше. Желательно в обе стороны

Comment: и что он вам при этом должен отображать?

Comment: @ZigZag, я знаю что надо ТС-у. Но не могу найти либу черт побери :) Это эффект такой, если в конце или начале списка проскроллить то выдвигается пустое пространство и при отпускании пальца это самое пространство сужается.

Comment: @Flippy да, именно, весь гугл прогуглил, не могу найти

Comment: либа точно есть, я писал под заказ список такой, использовал куски из либы дописывал, найду -> скину на самом деле там не так много когда.

Comment: Ищите по ключевым словам "iOS style")

Comment: @Flippy, не это либа случайно https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor

Comment: @Iman, именно :)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @Iman за ответ
github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/235117)

Comment: @AK, он фактически перетащил ответ из комментария...